# vyper integer default value

Tags: vyper

Here is what i have read on this vyper official documentation:

https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/types.html#initial-values

> int128   1

> uint256  1

I have create this very basic smartcontract:

```
variable_test: int128

@external
@view
def myfunction() -> int128:
  return self.variable_test
```

The myfunction function should return 1 according to the documentation, but it returns 0...

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That documentation can't possibly correct :-) Else you couldn't reliably convey the meaning of `1` (or `0`).

The docs you've linked to do appear to contradict with the values in the Vyper GitHub pages, which appear to make [more sense](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/blob/01c8299cec1c588d244facff4ec4783de2b5e6c2/docs/types.rst#initial-values):

```
Type    Default Value
address  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
bool    False
bytes32 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
decimal 0.0
int128  0
uint256 0
```

---

**Edit:**

In fact they were wrong on the GitHub pages as well until someone made a [PR](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/commit/1c80ba3fb87c5f5f460fd1a7b502d9eea16cdb1c) to correct them.